# hook_theme_suggestions_image_alter() not returning ['data-responsive-image-style']

Tags: theming, hooks

Perhaps I have similar issue to this [Drupal 9.2 template_preprocess_image hook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090860/drupal-9-2-template-preprocess-image-hook-not-working).

When I put this code in myTheme.theme

```
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)
{
 $responsive_style = $variables['attributes']['data-responsive-image-style'];
 $suggestions[] = 'image__'.$responsive_style;
}
```

The hook works good on inline images with this [module Inline responsive images](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_responsive_images) and it returns `['data-responsive-image-style']`.

But it doesn't work with regular article images, it returns `null`.

When I debug `$variables['attributes']` it has just this value

```
$variables[...] array (1)
  property => array (1)
    => string (12) "schema:image"
```

Comment: I use that module. The `data-responsive-image-style` is only added to text editor images only, it's not designed to work with image fields. For image fields you need to use core's responsive images module.

Comment: @NoSssweat That sounds like an answer.

Comment: I know that Inline responsive images module is used only for text editor, but it works fine. and return correct data $variables['attributes']['data-responsive-image-style']. 
I'm using core module for responsive images but in upper case it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.
I invoked from parent twig responsive_image_style_id

```
function hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'responsive_image') {
    $GLOBALS['responsive_image_style_id'] = $variables['responsive_image_style_id'];
  }
}

function hook_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'image') {
    return $suggestions[] = 'image__'.$GLOBALS['responsive_image_style_id'];
  }
}
```